# Why does Q[j] array indexing does not work after I have called it with Q++ in C?

Tags: arrays, c, indexing

This is one line small issue.

I have this code line that does not work correctly, because I have used `Q++` before.

If you look at this code

```
Q[j] += *Q * *Q; //  Power^2 -> Sum to the top row at column index j
```

This gives **** stack smashing detected ***:  terminated* error.

Why? Is it because I have used `Q++` before?
So if I have called `Q++` twice, then when I call `Q[0]`, I'm acctully calling `Q[2]`?

When I call `Q[j]`, I want to place the value at `row 0` at column `j`, which is between `0` and `Pcolumn`. How can I do that?

**Hint:**

If you replace this code:

```
Q[j] += *Q * *Q; //  Power^2 -> Sum to the top row at column index j
```

To

```
 *Q = *Q * *Q; //  Power^2
```

It's the same as MATLAB: Q = power(P-repmat(Q, 1, size(P, 2)), 2)

**How to repeat this issue:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define Pcolumns 10
#define Prows 3

// Repeat, substract, power and then sum
// MATLAB:
// Q = sum(power(P-repmat(Q, 1, size(P, 2)), 2), 1);
static void repmat_substract_power_sum(float Q[], const float P[]){
    // First row of Repeat -> Substract ->Power^2 -> Sum
    float q = *Q; // First column and first row value
    for(uint16_t j = 0; j < Pcolumns; j++){
        *Q = *P - q; // Substract
        *Q = *Q * *Q; // Power^2
        Q++;
        P++;
    }



    // The rest of the rows of Repeat -> Substract -> Power^2 -> Sum
    for(uint16_t i = 1; i < Prows; i++){
        q = *Q; // First column value at row i
        for(uint16_t j = 0; j < Pcolumns; j++){
            *Q = *P - q; // Substract
            Q[j] += *Q * *Q; //  Power^2 -> Sum to the top row at column index j
            Q++;
            P++;
        }
    }


}

int main()
{

    const float P[Prows*Pcolumns] = {-0.030123,  -0.163077,   0.218500,  -0.926896,  -0.159914,   2.344850,   0.473091,   0.039504,   0.590130,  -1.100642,
                                     -0.544295,   1.425373,  -0.337698,   1.440593,  -0.991939,  -0.457879,   0.136217,   0.173020,   0.947561,   0.596546,
                                     -0.145652,  -0.040126,  -0.835043,  -0.774521,  -0.333765,   1.586474, -1.811476,  -0.703679,  -1.382814,   0.406454};

    float Q[Prows*Pcolumns];
    Q[0] = 43;
    Q[Pcolumns*1] = -13;
    Q[Pcolumns*2] = 0.34;

    // Expected output on first row of Q: 2007.0   2071.3   1992.0   2139.3   2007.4   1811.7   1985.7   2020.2   1996.1   2129.7

    repmat_substract_power_sum(Q, P);


    for(int i = 0; i < Prows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Pcolumns; j++){
            printf("%f\t", Q[Pcolumns*i + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the 2nd loop you haven't reset `Q` which may be exhausted from the first loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Do I have to reset `Q`? I thougth that `Q` begins at index `0` when I first enter the function?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp But I have already written to `Q[j]` at the first row. `Q[j]` will only write to the first row.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes. That's because I do the first row - Done. Then I do the rest of the rows.

Comment: OK. If the first loop does not go through the entire array it is ok. The code is a bit confusing. `Q[j] += *Q * *Q; Q++;` You are indexing the array while modifying the pointer.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp So when I call `Q[j]` if `j = 4`. It does not mean that I'm going to go to index `4` right?

Comment: You are modifying `Q`. Ex: `j=0; Q[j] = 1, Q++; Q[j] = 1;` The first one writes to `(original)Q[0]` and the last one is actually writing to `(original)Q[1]` even though `j` has not changed.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I understand. So if I want to write at a specific location. I should not use the ++ signs? Or do you have any better idea?

Comment: One option is to just use indexing throughout. Another is to make a 2nd pointer and set it to `Q` which you can modify. Do indexing on one and dereferencing on the other.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I think I will use [] indexing all over the function. Proably solve the problem, but not so effective.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Do you think I can have negative index?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp `Q[j-Prows*i] += *Q * *Q;`

Comment: Yes. Negative indexes are OK _as long as the pointer is set up properly_. i.e. it points to the middle of the array. But you need to ensure it stays inside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes it will. This works `Q[j-Pcolumns*i] += *Q * *Q;` but did not give ge the correct result.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Here is the answe `Q[j-Pcolumns*i -j] += *Q * *Q;` :=)

Comment: Here's what I was going to suggest: https://ideone.com/AJPz45

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Does that resulting less assembler code?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Here `i * Pcolumns` you have another assembler statement.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Wait! I could just do `Q[-Pcolumns*i]` instead!

Comment: Unless you are dealing with _huge_ amounts of data, it won't matter. Another option is to use a running index: https://ideone.com/xsqjtF

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes. That's what I'm doing. Machine Learning on enbedded systems. I have a Git repo where I generate C-code that are optimal for image classification. Not sure if the last example you gave me will work, because `Q[index] += Q[index] * Q[index];` should be `Q[j] += Q[index] * Q[index];` :)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp By the way! Post an aswer and I will accept it. You have proven you worthy for that.